# Responsive Web Design for Navbar in Bootstrap not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I copied code from the getbootsrap.com for a navbar. I have made the navigation bar just how I like it, and the links works perfectly. When I shrink the browser, a button with three lines appears in the top right hand corner of the navigation bar. I added the links to bootstrap in the head, and followed the instructions on the website. I did not download the files, I added links to them so that the CSS can be updated by the bootstrap people.

Is this is a flaw in their code? Do I have to add more code to their code to make it work? If so, what code do I need to add, and where do I add it?

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mokha.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <img src="Bikers.png" height="100" width="125">
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="MokhaHOME.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Home</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="MokhaABOUT.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>About</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="MokhaSIGNIN.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Sign In</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="MokhaTIPS.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Tips</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="MokhaROUTES.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Routes</b></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">    </span> 
              </button>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: We need to see your code in order to give help to you. What code did you copy?

Comment: we need to see your code?

Comment: What is not working?? Your question is more of a statement rather than a question

Comment: Don't be lazy. Download the code

Answer (score 0):

The expandable navbar `.navbar-collapse` requires `bootstrap.js` to be included: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

`jQuery` is required too.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a flaw in their code, those 3 lines are dropdown menu intended for your links in header, you can disable them, or modify them to suit your needs..

Comment: Also, read about viewport tag for bootstrap, and post your code here if you need help...

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to happen. the page is responsive meaning it adapts to whatever size your screen is and reposition and changes elements.

Comment: But when I click on it it is not dropping  the menu down. None of my tabs show up.